# How to add a Unicode symbol to a Microsoft teams tab title

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am creating a app for Microsoft Teams. I am trying to create a tab using microsoft graph post api.

`/teams/${teamId}/channels/${channelId}/tabs` payload is an object with following params:

```
{
   displayName: 'My Tab'
   'teamsApp@odata.bind': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.web',
   configuration: {…},
};
```

Currently creating Tab with tab name 'My Tab'. How can I prepend a unicode logo along with name. e.g. '+unicode-logo + My Tab'. Unicode logo is available to a particular font file.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way to add unicode logo along with name while creating tab using Graph API.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be any way to add unicode logo along with name while creating tab using Graph API. Supported type is string.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teamstab?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties